# help with c# timer

Tags: c#, timer

i have this timer in c#:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public int count = 0;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onTimer);
        timer.Start();
        return View();
    }
    public void onTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
    }  
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckStatus()
    {
        return Json(count);
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // poll every 5 seconds
    setInterval('checkStatus()', 3000);
});

function checkStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/CheckStatus',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (xhr_data) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerText = xhr_data;
        }
    });
}
```

Why does it keep show me (when running) only 0 ? why doesn't it show me: 0,1,2 etc.. ?

Comment: Because a new instance of `HomeController` is instantiated every time you `POST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new instance of the controller will be created each time you make a request. Thus your repeated AJAX calls just get 0, since that's what the `count` value is initialized to.

There will likely be other controllers (with timers running) floating around until the GC runs to collect them, but they will have no effect on the new controller that is actually processing each individual request.

I don't know what problem you're trying to solve with this code, but have you investigated the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` javascript methods? They provide client-side timer services, and might be well-suited for your task.

If you need persistent server-side data, then there are number of options, including:

- [Session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972429(v=msdn.10))
- [Application state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/bf9xhdz4(v=vs.71))
- [ViewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972976(v=msdn.10))
- [The Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.71))

Which, if any, are right for you depends on the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'd put a disclaimer on the static fields.  The worker process in IIS can be recycled at any time, binning the static fields with it.

Comment: @Adam Good point. I included them last as a *very* subtle way to suggest not to use them, but they're just a bad idea. Removed.

Comment: @dlev, what i'm trying to do is this:
i have this class which get throw the modbus RTU protocol some data from a sensor. after getting the data, the class does some mathematics stuff on it, and save the result in a variable.
i want my view to show this variable all the time with its most updated value.
i thought doing it by putting a javascript interval which will get the update from the JsonResult controller. 
for now it works, but i would love to hear if there are more ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Because your timer won't survive the page lifecycle, assuming this is ASP.NET.  Every time a postback occurs, a fresh instance will be given.

I'm not sure how to get the timer to work, but to get stuff persisted across callbacks, you use something like View State, Session, or Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the controller instantiated each time a request is made, so the value will be zero each time you make a request?

If you want a global counter, use Application or a static field.  If you want it to count per user use session.

Comment: but i only load the index() once, and the timer in the view call the CheckStatus method... why is it zeroing all the time ?

Comment: Should i change the count to be static ? or the timer ?